# WPF charting tool kit - Multiple Scatter series - Data Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, charts, scatter-plot

I am able to display a single scatter series called FinalResult via the WPF charting tool kit.

```
 public List<KeyValuePair<double,double>> FinalResult
    {
        get
        {
            return _finalResult;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_finalResult == value) return;
            _finalResult = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FinalResult");
        }
    }
    public List<KeyValuePair<double, double>> _finalResult;
```

In the Xaml, I just called this property as :

```
<chartingToolkit:Chart Name="lineChart" Background = "White" Title="CDF - Charting Kit">
            <chartingToolkit:ScatterSeries DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key"  IsSelectionEnabled="True" 
                                               ItemsSource="{Binding FinalResult}" />

            <chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
                <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis Orientation="Y" ShowGridLines="True" />

                <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis Orientation="X" ShowGridLines="True" />

            </chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
        </chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

Now the next step is to display multiple scatter series. I thought I could use observation collection like this and use that property in the XAML but now I dont see any chart. Here is the code for that:

```
public class CDFPlot
    {
       public List<KeyValuePair<double, double>> FinalResult1 { get; set; }
    }
    ObservableCollection<CDFPlot> CDFresults = new ObservableCollection<CDFPlot>();
    public ObservableCollection<CDFPlot> CDFResults
    {
        get { return CDFresults; }
        set
        {
            CDFresults = value;
            base.OnPropertyChanged("StringList");
        }
    }
```

and then in the xaml side, I did binding to "FinalResult1".

```
 <chartingToolkit:Chart Name="lineChart" Background = "White" Title="CDF - Charting Kit">
            <chartingToolkit:ScatterSeries DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key"  IsSelectionEnabled="True" 
                                               ItemsSource="{Binding FinalResult1}" />

            <chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
                <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis Orientation="Y" ShowGridLines="True" />

                <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis Orientation="X" ShowGridLines="True" />

            </chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
        </chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

When I run the debug, I can see that the CDFPLOT.FinalResult1 is populated.
Am I binding it correctly? Please advise on how can I fix it?

Another workaround that I have tried so far is to build the chart in the code and not via xaml..

```
 private void showChart()
    {
        CDF_PAnalysisPluginModel model = DataContext as CDF_PAnalysisPluginModel;

        LineSeries lineSeries1 = new LineSeries();

        lineSeries1.Title = "Title";
        lineSeries1.DependentValuePath = "Value";
        lineSeries1.IndependentValuePath = "Key";

            foreach (var x in model.CDFResults)
            {

                lineSeries1.ItemsSource = x.FinalResult1;

             lineChart.Series.Add(lineSeries1);  // error on this line

            }

    }
```

and xaml being:

```
<chartingToolkit:Chart Name="lineChart" Background = "White" Title="CDF - Charting Kit">
</chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

but I get error on the line as mentioned.

Comment: Becuase I find currently open source charting libraries not so good, I made this 10 days ago https://github.com/beto-rodriguez/Live-Charts, maybe it can help you it includes many examples, animated and easy to customize

Comment: What is your `DataContext` assigned to? Your code doesn't show that important piece of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works, assuming `DataContext` was properly assigned, like below:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:CDFPlot/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <chartingToolkit:Chart Name="lineChart" Background = "White" Title="CDF - Charting Kit">
        <chartingToolkit:ScatterSeries DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key"  IsSelectionEnabled="True" 
                                           ItemsSource="{Binding FinalResult1}" />

        <chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
            <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis Orientation="Y" ShowGridLines="True" />

            <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis Orientation="X" ShowGridLines="True" />

        </chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
    </chartingToolkit:Chart>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Now, please note that `FinalResult1` can only hold data for one single `ScatterSeries`, not multiple ones like you want.

**EDIT**: This is how I added multiple series using your initial code:

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <local:CDFViewModel/>
    </Grid.DataContext>
    <chartingToolkit:Chart x:Name="chart1" Margin="0" Title="Chart Title">
        <chartingToolkit:ScatterSeries DependentValuePath="Y" IndependentValuePath="X" ItemsSource="{Binding CDFPlotCollection[0]}">
        </chartingToolkit:ScatterSeries>
        <chartingToolkit:ScatterSeries DependentValuePath="Y" IndependentValuePath="X" ItemsSource="{Binding CDFPlotCollection[1]}">
        </chartingToolkit:ScatterSeries>
    </chartingToolkit:Chart>
</Grid>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class CDFViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<CDFPlot> CDFPlotCollection { get; set; }

    public CDFViewModel()
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        CDFPlotCollection = new ObservableCollection<CDFPlot>();

        CDFPlotCollection.Add(new CDFPlot(r, 0));
        CDFPlotCollection.Add(new CDFPlot(r, 2));
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class CDFPlot : ObservableCollection<Point>
{
    public CDFPlot(Random r, double delta)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            Add(new Point { X = i, Y = delta+r.NextDouble() });
    }
}
```

[image]

**EDIT 2**: Or you can obtain the same result using code behind:

XAML:

```
<chartingToolkit:Chart x:Name="chart1" Margin="0" Title="Chart Title">
    </chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

Window.cs:

```
     private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CDFViewModel model = new CDFViewModel();
        ScatterSeries series;

        for (int i = 0; i < model.CDFPlotCollection.Count; i++)
        {
            series = new ScatterSeries();
            series.DependentValuePath = "Y";
            series.IndependentValuePath = "X";
            series.ItemsSource = model.CDFPlotCollection[i];
            chart1.Series.Add(series);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @jstreet . It works for one series on my machine. How do I show multiple series on the same chart? Is it possible via XAML or should I code in the background? I tried this in the xaml.cs file but its giving me error pertaining to duplication series..

Comment: Well, in theory you could do it either way, via XAML or code behind. If you get an error, then you need to post your stack trace and relevant code, otherwise I cannot guess what the problem is. For one thing, your one-line XAML above is missing the closing `backlash character`. Also, please post code for `CDF_PAnalysisPluginModel`.

Comment: I updated my post with some sample code for multiple series. See if it helps.

Comment: Thanks!! Yes in your scenario, you already know that there will be two series and hence in xaml it can be mentioned explicitly but in my scenario, the number of series is dynamic; could be 2 or 4 or 1 ; depending on what user selects.

Comment: Like I said, it is possible to do it either way. In your case you have to do it through code behind then...